# Windows 10 downloadable ISO

Tags: windows-10, oem

Will the downloadable Windows 10 ISO support an OEM license?

I have all the parts to build a computer but the only thing that didn't come in was the OEM disc.  If I load windows from the downloadable ISO, will it accept the key from the disc once it comes in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just make sure you install the correct version to match what you bought.

i.e. Base, Professional, etc.